# load an high number of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, preloader

I'm developing a website that allows the user to see and configure a product.
I wanted to start this project using jquery, css3 and html5 with a graceful degradation for older browsers.

I've combined all the smallest images in several sprites to reduce the number of http requests (the images will be served from a cookieless subdomain).
By the way the product must be viewable in 360° for each combination of configurations.
This produces 2252 images (15mb total).

This is not a big issue for the bandwitdh since we have 2 dedicated servers, but I'm just thinking about the best way to improve the user experience.

Actually I only preload images for the default product view, then when the user changes settings I load the needed images (jQuery helps here). When the images are loading the user will se a "loading" gif. Should I preload images also when it does not request them?

Images will be cached by the browser so each image will be a 304 Not Modified response.
Do you have any advice or suggestion to improve the user experience?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have 2252 images per product and you preload one, it seems a bit futile to start preloading others.  Presumably the viewer changes his selection and you need another one of the 2252 images. That's a very low chance that you'd have that image preloaded.

If there are various "attributes" that are more common than others, you might want to preload a select few?  For example, (I don't know what your product is), if you have a red shirt and a pink plaid XXXL shirt, you might want to preload the red one first ;)

One thing I do in situations like this is to play with the animation effects in jQuery (fade, slide, etc).  You can fadeOut on attribute change.  That animation will take perhaps 600 milliseconds which would be a good chunk of the time required to go and fetch that image from the server.  The result is a perceived lower waiting time for the new view/attribute.

Comment: Great idea :)
Maybe I should play with effects as you do.
Thanks for sharing this, expecially the first part is very important for me to keep in mind for the future to evaluate if I should preload everything or not.

Answer (score 1):

Serving the images from a CDN like amazon s3 might improve the load times a little. As for preloading in steps - that might depend on the product. Somethings are more likely to be rotated - for example a car over what landon said. I personally wouldn't bother rotating a t shirt, but a car probably. So the decision might be based on the expected use of your site.

Comment: I was also thinking to rely on a CDN, but I was stopped by the system engineer that is sure our performance will be excellent

Comment: your system performance may be excellent, but the advantages of a cdn surpass the first glance evaluation. For example, our edgecast cdn is delegated to 5 different servers, maximizing the number of simultaneous connections and images being served, dramatically reducing load times. Additionally, it is regional so overseas users are distributed evenly. so we rotate each image call by referencing a cdn server sequence: http://cdn.somesite.com/images/1.jpg, http://cdn2.somesite.com/images/2.jpg, etc

Comment: Other thing a CDN should give you is reduced latency as the CND boxes are at the network edge and geo-dispersed. Other thing that would be worth doing is setting the caching headers correctly to avoid the browser doing if-modified-since requests and getting the 304 back